# I keep getting null pointer exception on my getArguments();

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

From a list, the user can click and item and a fragment will inflate showing the data for the clicked item, where the user also can edit that data and click save to save the edited data.

But from the screen that contains the list is also an add button if the user wants to create a new object.

When the user clicks on an item from the list, a `newInstance(..);` is called
and in the Fragments `onCreateView();` I initilize all variables for that clicked item in the different views. But that is not working well because I keep getting:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.os.Bundle.getInt(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference`

**newInstance is called from the RecyclerView Adapter onClick():**

```
  public static CreateTrainingFragment newInstance(ItemModel itemModel) {

    bundle = new Bundle();

    bundle.putInt(SB_DURATION, itemModel.getDuration());
    bundle.putInt(SB_DISTANCE, itemModel.getDistance());


    CreateTrainingFragment createTrainingFragment = new CreateTrainingFragment();
    createTrainingFragment.setArguments(bundle);


    return createTrainingFragment;
}
```

**Here I use getArguments(); and feed the arguments into Views:**
Would the default 0 variable not automatically be inserted into my `sbduration.setProgress();` if the argument dont exist?

```
private void initArgumentsData() {


        sbduration.setProgress(getArguments().getInt(SB_DURATION, 0));
        sbDistance.setProgress(getArguments().getInt(SB_DISTANCE, 0));


        txtduration.setText(getArguments().getInt(SB_DURATION, 0) + " min");
        txtDistance.setText(getArguments().getInt(SB_DISTANCE, 0) + " km");


}
```

**Here is how my Views is created and where I use InitArgumentData();**

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.createtraining_layout, container, false);

    sbduration = (SeekBar) v.findViewById(R.id.seekbar_time);
    sbDistance = (SeekBar) v.findViewById(R.id.seekbar_distance);


    txtduration = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.time_value);
    txtDistance = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.distance_value);


    sbduration.setMax(100);
    sbDistance.setMax(50);



    initArgumentsData();
}
```

**From RecyclerView I start a new fragment instance like this:**

```
  itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                ItemModel itemModel = realm.getDefaultInstance().where(ItemModel.class).equalTo("timestamp",list.get(getAdapterPosition()).getTimestamp()).findFirst();
                CreateTrainingFragment createTrainingFragment = CreateTrainingFragment.newInstance(itemModel, true);

                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.navdrawer_maincontainer,createTrainingFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

            }
        });
```

**From the add button the Fragment is started like this:**

```
addbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.navdrawer_maincontainer,new CreateTrainingFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();

        }
    });
```

Comment: How do you start the new fragment instance?

Comment: Could you post full code of RecyclerView Adapter.

Comment: bundle = new Bundle(); Why not bundle variable is method local. Just like to verify, this bundle variable is not set to null from anywhere

Comment: @fluffyBatman the new Fragment instance, where the user can create a new object can either be started from a "add button" to create a new object or by clicking on item from a list where this item's data will be transfered to the fragments instance via newInstance and be put inside the seekbars and edittext

Comment: @rahulkapoor I made the bundle local again. I have posted the only lines that instanties a Fragment instance. The whole class is not nessercery

Comment: @fluffyBatman I only get this exception when I start a new Fragment Instance via the add button, but not when I click an item fom the list

Comment: @Muddz I actually asked for the code you use to start the fragment through that button.

Comment: @fluffyBatman Oh allright I just posted it at the bottom now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.navdrawer_maincontainer,new CreateTrainingFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Here, you're using `new CreateTrainingFragment()`. Hence, you're not getting the bundle since there is no bundle attach to it. You should call the `newInstance` method first to get the an object of CreateTrainingFragment and then put it on replace.

```
ItemModel itemModel = realm.getDefaultInstance().where(ItemModel.class).equalTo("timestamp",list.get(getAdapterPosition()).getTimestamp()).findFirst();
CreateTrainingFragment createTrainingFragment = CreateTrainingFragment.newInstance(itemModel, true);

getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.navdrawer_maincontainer, createTrainingFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Comment: Should I first create an object of `CreateTrainingFragment`or call `newInstance`?

Comment: Both will do. What's the name of the class that holds newInstance method?

Comment: that is `CreateTrainingFragment`

Comment: Thanks it works. So my method `initArgumentsData()` didn't work because I initiated the Fragment without a bundle.

Comment: Exactly! Your way of putting data in bundle and getting it from Fragment looked fine to me. Only option there to check was transaction of new fragment.

Answer (score 0):

How about you just check if the arguments exist?

```
private void initArgumentsData() {

    Bundle args = getArguments();

    int duration = 0;
    int distance = 0;

    if (args != null) {
        duration = args.getInt(SB_DURATION, 0);
        distance = args.getInt(SB_DISTANCE, 0);
    } 
    sbduration.setProgress(duration);
    sbDistance.setProgress(distance);

    txtduration.setText(duration + " min");
    txtDistance.setText(distance + " km");
}
```

Even if you did call `newInstance` on the Fragment, you still would need to provide a `new ItemModel` to that method.

Comment: I just tried your solution and it worked too. So which of two answers are best practice?

Comment: Well, my solution completely handles the NullPointerException at the expense of maintainability for additional fields. The other answer (while correct) failed to add the `new ItemModel`, like I said. Either way, I'd say a combination of both.

Comment: Actually I have used your solution because its more obvious what happends and where and less code.